# IBM Worklight - License Information

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have just been handed over a Worklight Server, set up by my Ex-Colleague, and I need to know where can I find the License information, as if the Product is registered on my company name and when the Renewal date is.

How can I find the License information, I have tried using IBM Installation Manager > Manage License option, but it doesn't show any Worklight related Products in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow me to clarify:

1. Worklight Developer Edition - can be freely downloaded from the Eclipse Marketplace.
2. Worklight Consumer/Enterprise Edition - can be obtained once you have purchased IBM Worklight.

There is no "license information" in the product itself; you do not register it to a specific name or company.

You should consult with the procurement personnel in your company, or whomever did the IBM Worklight deal in your company to understand the nature of the deal - renewal date, amount of applications allowed to develop and so on.

You can also [contact IBM Worklight](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/worklight/), but it would make more sense for you to figure this out in-house.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, just one more clarification, I have a running Worklight Consumer Edition, so this means the product is registered? I was concerned if by any chance I am running some Trial versions etc?

Comment: The thing is Company has purchased the Worklight, I can see the it in IBM Passport as well, but I am not sure if the person who installed it for the first time used the proper files (registered on the company name) or installed Evaluation version.

Comment: If you are running the Consumer edition then you are "registered", yes. If you are unsure if you are running it, uninstall it and install the correct files. If your question is answered, please mark as Answered. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am running Consumer Edition for sure, since it shows Worklight Server and I have deployed the fixes myself.

Comment: Actually Re-installing everything is a path I don;t want to choose :) Thanks for the help !! Much Appreciated.